# pass variable within Cypher query in python

Tags: python, flask, neo4j, cypher

I have 2 variables

```
 name='name1234'
 age='21'
```

and a neo4j cypher query

```
query33= 'CREATE (k:user { Username: @name, Userage: '@age' })'
```

how i can pass the two variables ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it via format: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format

```
query33= "CREATE (k:user {{ Username: {name}, Userage: '{age}' }})".format(name='name1234', age=21)
query33
"CREATE (k:user { Username: name1234, Userage: '21' })"
```